# Passing QueryString Value For Silverlight Grid Row

Tags: silverlight, binding, mvvm

How is it possible to do multivalue binding in Silverlight?

I have to determine the Visibility of a Silverlight DataGrid column depending on the value present as part of Datacontext and other one from the QueryString.

I use MVVM Model of silverlight 5 and my plan is currently to define a property for querystring in code behind that can be binded to row visibility. But my problem clearly here is to pass multiple values for the IValueConverter implementation.

Can anyone provide a simple example to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi binding is not supported out of the box in Silverlight.

But with the introduction of customer markup extensions in Silverlight 5, this can be achieved.
There's a good example on code project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/286171/MultiBinding-in-Silverlight-5.

Alternatively, in this particular example you can have public boolean a property in your view model which uses the QueryString Value along with the other value you are concerned in DataContext and decides whether the column needs to be visible or not. You can then databind this property to your column's **IsVisible** property. (Along with a value converter which returns **Visbility.Visble** /**Visibility.Collapsed** depending on the value of the boolean property value)

Comment: Thanks for the Solution. I just added the variable as a static variable for my IValueConverter and the whole thing just works!! Thanks!!